# How to fill placeholder with filename from input field using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Like the topic states, i want to get the filename of selected file, and then fill in the filename to the placeholder, i don’t want to use the class since this are being cloned dynamically as well.

I have made a attempt finding the closest element, with no success.
Could this be done using closest() / find() or prev()?

```
<div class="col-md-10">
        <div class="input-group">
            <label class="input-group-btn">
                <span class="btn btn-primary">
                    Browse <input class="documentation" type="file" name="documentation[]" >
                </span>
            </label>
            <input value="" type="text" class="form-control file-placeholder" readonly>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        $('.documentation').change(function () {
            var filename = $(this).val();
            $(this).closest('.file-placeholder').find('.file-placeholder').val(filename);
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: `.closest('.file-placeholder').find('.file-placeholder')` ???

Comment: I need a alternative code to fill in the filname of choosen file to the placeholder, so far this is just some example code,

Comment: @sdfgg45 But what you want is `.closest('.input-group').find('.file-placeholder')`

Comment: allright :) Seams that input-group does the trick.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(this).parent().parent().siblings('.file-placeholder')` selector should be used to give selected filename as value to nearest text field.

```js
$('.documentation').on('change',function () {
  var filename = $(this).val();
  $(this).parent().parent().siblings('.file-placeholder').val(filename);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-10">
  <div class="input-group">
    <label class="input-group-btn">
      <span class="btn btn-primary">
        Browse <input class="documentation" type="file" name="documentation[]" >
      </span>
    </label>
    <input value="" type="text" class="form-control file-placeholder" readonly>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use $('.documentation').on('change',function () { delegate selector. Which will be useful in cloned elements as well. Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this line:

```
$(this).closest('.file-placeholder').find('.file-placeholder').val(filename);
```

change it to:

```
$(this).closest('.input-group-btn').next('.file-placeholder').val(filename);
```

The snippet:

```js
$('.documentation').change(function () {
  var filename = $(this).val();
  $(this).closest('.input-group-btn').next('.file-placeholder').val(filename);
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="col-md-10">
    <div class="input-group">
        <label class="input-group-btn">
                <span class="btn btn-primary">
                    Browse <input class="documentation" type="file" name="documentation[]" >
                </span>
        </label>
        <input value="" type="text" class="form-control file-placeholder" readonly>
    </div>
</div>
```